# HTTP request with geolocation coordinates

Tags: html, xml, forms, httprequest

I have a feeling that I'm asking something that was already asked and answered. I tried to find this answer, but couldn't. I did find [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243596/passing-geo-location-obtained-by-javascript-into-a-html-form-to-be-sent-to-a-dat), but it is too complex for me to understand.
I'd like to send a webhook that has the user's current location as one of the parameters.
I'm not a developer so I'm unable to understand how to use XML and JS as part of an HTML page.
Here are some of the building blocks that I've found, without the knowledge of how to combine them to work together:

1. [Geolocation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation)
2. [Sending Form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

Is there an easy (low-code) option to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: `"Is there an easy (low-code) option to achieve this?"` - not really. You are expected to write code with which you are having issues rather than formulate a request for work... no doubt many on SO could do it but your question is basically off-topic

Comment: I seek guidance. I'm not asking anyone to write a code for me :)